# Function return value array and boolean so What is the return type of this function in php?

Tags: php

I have a function like below. It return array value and boolean value so i want to know how to define function return type? what is the return type of this function?

```
public function alert($id): ____ //this place value?
{
            $model = Model::find($id);
            if ($model) {
                if ($model->status != 1) {
                    return array(
                        'header' => 'Failed',
                        'message' => 'Failed related message'
                    );
                } else {
                    return array(
                        'header' => 'Success',
                        'message' => 'Success related message.'
                    );
                }
            }
            return false;
}
```

Comment: There is functionality built in php to get the variable type - `gettype()`. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-gettype-function/#:~:text=The%20gettype()%20function%20is,the%20type%20of%20existing%20variable. There is also `settype()` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php

Comment: Thanks @mech for your response. i didn't understand from your answer related with my question. my question is without defining anything in _____ it's working fine. but i want to know how to define return type for this type of condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method to define return value:

```
public function alert($id): ? array
{
            $model = Model::find($id);
            if ($model) {
                if ($model->status != 1) {
                    return array(
                        'header' => 'Failed',
                        'message' => 'Failed related message'
                    );
                } else {
                    return array(
                        'header' => 'Success',
                        'message' => 'Success related message.'
                    );
                }
            }
            return null;
}
```

Which will end up in result of null or array.

Comment: to return false?

Comment: I do not think that it is any reason, You can define in function definition @return property like mixed and comment it that it will return null or array in your example.